# Conditional join in SQL Server dependent on other table values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need make a decision which table should be use in join statement depend on values in another table

I tried using `CASE` and `COALESCE` but can't achieve any success.

- TableA has A and B and C and many other  columns
- TableB has ID and NAME columns
- TableC has ID and NAME columns

My select statement is;

`Select A.D, A.E, A.F From TableA A`

If `A.E = 1` then the following join should be used

`left outer join TableB B ON A.B = B.ID`

and `B.NAME` should be returned in the select statement

If `A.E = 2` then the following join should be used

`left outer join TableC C ON A.B = C.ID`

and `C.NAME` should be returned in the select statement

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, along with your attempt(s) will be really helpful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add your conditions to the joins, and then use a case statement to pull the correct field to your result set e.g.

```
select A.D, A.E, A.F
  , case when B.[Name] is not null then B.[Name] else C.[Name] end [Name]
from TableA A
left outer join TableB B ON A.B = B.ID and A.E = 1
left outer join TableC C ON A.B = C.ID and A.E = 2
```

Comment: You could also use `coalesce()` to simplify the case statement since there would never be a case when B.* and C.* are both not null.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its working very well. Saving my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Join `tablea` with the `union` of `tableb` with an extra column with value `1` and `tablec`  with an extra column with value `2` and apply the conditions in the `ON` clause:

```
select 
  a.D, a.E, a.F, u.NAME
from tablea a
left join (
  select *, 1 col from tableb
  union all
  select *, 2 col from tablec
) u on a.B = u.id and a.E = u.col
```